# Why do we set property sets as private in domain objects for CQRS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, microservices

I am a bit confused so to why we set the `set` as private in the following. My confusion is not specifically to do with the private property, but in the context of domain objects and getting them from the user input ([FromForm])

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public ObjectA(string name, string title)
    {
        Name = name;
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

But in reality when ObjectA is passed into a controller with [FromBody], all those properties get sent into the constructor automatically defeating the purpose of `private set`.

I guess I am not fully understanding this whole concept of private sets in domain objects

Comment: So it can't me mutated from outside. Though `public string Name { get; }` is better, making it read only except for within the constructor

Comment: But in the case of this being passed from the asp.net controller, it is being changed through the ctor of ObjectA since those values are passed through the ctor.

I guess I am confused on the fact that why and who possible can set this object any different than how the asp.net controller is mutating it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin  In reality I have the following `CreateSomethingCommand` that has private sets (the one being questioned in this question) then after i validate `CreateSomethingCommand` then I have an actual entity object `SomethingEntity`, i transfer info from this and ultimately save the entity to db.  Is this not the recommended way to do it, and arent both `CreateSomethingCommand` and `SomethingEntity` considered "domain objects"/

Comment: Note that there is no rule that says “when using CQRS, use private setters”. This is mostly about API design and for a lot of situations, it does not really matter that much. If you want to know why you found this example, then you should ask the author why they did it that way; maybe they have a reason for it. Other than that, this is mostly personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

It's common rule when design DDD objects. makes object to be immutable. Property's value should be changed only inside your domain via constructor or public method. That helps you more focus to your domain and avoid side effects.

Kind of these objects are not the Data Transfer Object(DTO) that you mentioned: [FromBody]